# show dates in rows as dynamic columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

**EDIT**
None of the suggested answers confront the issue of dynamic dates as columns.

I need columns to be last 4 week_start and next week_start

Need to turn this:

```
+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------+
|  ID   |  Name  |      week_start      | weekly_value |
+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------+
| 10739 | Monica | 2020-12-27T00:00:00Z |           49 |
| 10739 | Monica | 2021-01-03T00:00:00Z |           49 |
| 10739 | Monica | 2021-01-10T00:00:00Z |           49 |
| 10739 | Monica | 2021-01-17T00:00:00Z |           49 |
| 10064 | Sarah  | 2020-12-27T00:00:00Z |           93 |
| 10064 | Sarah  | 2021-01-03T00:00:00Z |           93 |
| 10064 | Sarah  | 2021-01-10T00:00:00Z |           93 |
| 10064 | Sarah  | 2021-01-17T00:00:00Z |           93 |
| 10064 | Sarah  | 2021-01-24T00:00:00Z |           93 |
| 16689 | Jacqui | 2020-12-27T00:00:00Z |           89 |
| 16689 | Jacqui | 2021-01-03T00:00:00Z |           89 |
| 16689 | Jacqui | 2021-01-10T00:00:00Z |           89 |
| 16689 | Jacqui | 2021-01-17T00:00:00Z |           89 |
| 16689 | Jacqui | 2021-01-24T00:00:00Z |           89 |
+-------+--------+----------------------+--------------+
```

into this

```
+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  ID   |  Name   | 12/27/2020 | 1/3/2021 | 1/10/2021 | 1/17/2021 | 1/24/2021 |
+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 10739 | Monica  |         49 |       49 |        49 |        49 | null      |
| 10064 | Sarah   |         93 |       93 |        93 |        93 | 93        |
| 16689 | Jacqui  |         89 |       89 |        89 |        89 | 89        |
+-------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

and **those dates will change every week**

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a normal pivot table, only as source you have to select only the dates you need

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('MAX(IF(`week_start` = "', `week_start`,'", `weekly_value`,0)) AS "',DATE(`week_start`),'"')
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM (SELECT * FROM value WHERE `week_start` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK  AND NOW()) t1;
>
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.`ID`, s.`Name`,  ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM (SELECT * FROM value WHERE `week_start` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK  AND NOW()) s
>                  GROUP BY s.`ID`, s.`Name`
>                  ORDER BY s.`ID`');
> #SELECT @sql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
>    ID | Name   | 2020-12-27 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-17
> ----: | :----- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
> 10064 | Sarah  |         93 |         93 |         93 |         93
> 10739 | Monica |         49 |         49 |         49 |         49
> 16689 | Jacqui |         89 |         89 |         89 |         89
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6549162b0f17de65dc658be1eb0376ad)*